# AppDelegate is not being called

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, breakpoints, appdelegate

I can't seem to get my appdelegate to be called at all. Using breakpoints it doesn't even seem like the first like is being called.

This is what I have in my main.m

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppDelegatename");
[pool release];
return retVal;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Let say your `AppDelegate` is `MyAppDelegate`, defined in `MyAppDelegate.h` and `MyAppDelegate.m`.

Try with this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MyAppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([MyAppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

EDIT: This is ofcourse ment for ARC-enabled app. In case you are not using ARC you should consider unsing it. If you insist with non-ARC approach then just replace your line:

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppDelegatename");
```

with

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([MyAppDelegate class]));
```

In both cases you have to replace `MyAppDelegate` with the real name of your application delegate class.

EDIT2:

According to your additional commands your main.m should look something like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Radio99AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([Radio99AppDelegate class]));
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
}
```

I'm not sure if you are using radio99AppDelegate or Radio99AppDelegate - the last one would be 'standard'. And if this is a new project it would be wise to consider 'translating' it to ARC. Much less hussle with memory management.

Comment: Okay I took the later option but I keep getting an undeclared identifier "MyAppDelegate" where that is the name of my application delegate class. Is there anywhere else I should be declaring the name of the class?

Comment: MyAppDelegate is used just as an example here. You have to use the real values from your project. Where (in what .h file) is your appDelegate defined? And what is the name of it's class?

Comment: Basically I'm trying to edit a app template for a streaming radio station. The way that it came it seems that the appdelegate was never used. The original main.m was:

    `int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
    }`

The name of the main appdelegate is radio99AppDelegate.m and there's a .h as well

Comment: I edited my answer. if this doesn't work please post your Radio99AppDelegate.h

Comment: Okay thanks! That sorted my undeclared issue out however the breakpoints still telling me that it's not being run at all. The breakpoints work in the viewcontrollers so it's not an issue with them. Any other ideas?

Comment: Hmm, where are you setting your breakpoints? I don't think it will work in main.m. Try to set breakpoint somewhere in `application:didFinishLaunching:withOptions` instead. If your app runs then rest asured that your appDelegate is being called.

Comment: I have this: application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:... and its not called at all.

Comment: Hmm. Are you getting any compiler errors? Does your app run at all?

Answer (score 1):

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

Answer (score 0):

I was migrating a legacy app to iOS 9.2 and ran into this problem.  In my main method I had to pass the AppDelegate's class name as the principalClassName parameter as well as the delegateClassName parameter of UIApplicationMain.

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]), NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```